# .caf to mp3 converting with lame not working on ios 8

Tags: ios, avfoundation, ios8, xcode6, lame

I am using lame in my project ı record any sound with avfoundation. Saving as .caf and ı want to convert it to mp3 file format. I downloaded ios 8 in my project so lame is give me this error :

```
APPLE MACH-O Linker Eroor
linker command failed with exit code 1(use -1 to see invocation)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdcg9ikf0sra7xj/Screenshot%202014-09-19%2016.59.57.png

Comment: Please post the error than an image. And there is a few question about that kind of error. Did you look at them?

Comment: it is saying that your lame framework is missing some files.,delete framework and import again. clean and build.

Comment: its working on my similator correctly this error appear only on device ? This is not framework problem.

Comment: then check architectures in build settings.,tell me what do you have?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uo7conmuc96mb6/Screenshot%202014-09-19%2017.39.44.png?dl=0

Comment: Hey i removed arm64 on architectures and problem fixed.